# Get photos back from broken/locked android phone

Tags: hardware

Is there any way to open mobile phone and get it's ROM memory out and connect it with pc or something and get your files(photos and text files) ?

Comment: Duplicate of: [How to perform a full system dump/backup with a broken screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54272/how-to-perform-a-full-system-dump-backup-with-a-broken-screen)

Comment: Related: [How to get data off a completely dead Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215445/218526)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to transfer the internal memory/storage chip of an S9?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217018/2241)