# Secure boot requires PIN (2 tries left untill factory reset the phone)

Tags: boot

I have a situation where I recently set PIN, activated Secure boot and booted up my phone and entered the PIN incorrectly 28 times. Now I have two times to enter the PIN correctly else the phone will be reset to factory defaults (images, all data deleted) which I want to avoid.

Do you think it's possible to reset the number of tries again to 30 for secure boot if I already used 28 times? The phone which I am using is Samsung S9+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

secure startup means android is not booted therefore FindMyMobile not available. counter can be reset in [crypto footer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4168821) but that requires raw access via chip-off method (or samsung signed firehose programmer if your device is qualcomm usa model)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.
Do you think that it's possible to disable secure startup in such a situation? If the phone would bootup, I could use finger print or face ID.

Comment: DEK is re-encrypted with new KEK and PIN. the only way back is factory reset

Comment: Thank you! I just have few more question:
I desperately trying because I have some vacation photos inside my phone and I am very afraid to lose it.


1. Do You think if I flash custom recovery such as TWRP would I be able to BACKUP everything to an external SD card and use two PIN guesses, then if I fail and the device is the factory reset - restore from SD card using TWRP and try again two more times until success?

Comment: 2. Do you think such a solution would work? to Install TWRP and using in-built File Manager and deleting following files inside /data/system folder:
Gatekeeper.password.key
gatekeeper.pattern.key
locksettings.db
locksettings.db-shm
locksettings.db-wal


3. In such a situation, would you bring such a device to Samsung support? I doubt if they could help

4. Do you think I am completely screwed and I should reset to the factory and forget the photos?

Comment: no. there is some cheat to by-pass gatekeeper via emergency call menu but requires android. /data/system is encrypted and TWRP not flashable on locked bootloader

Comment: Do you think it's possible to mount my Samsung to try PIN guesses without counting towards 30 PIN guess limit (like on Secure Startup)? I thought maybe if I guess over my pc, perhaps it wouldn't be counted but I never managed to mount my Samsung partitions on PC

Comment: there is absolutely nothing you can do besides backup/altering crypto footer via [chip-off](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217018) method or [EDL](https://alephsecurity.com/2018/01/22/qualcomm-edl-1) mode

Comment: Thank you so much, I am very thankful. All the best for you